# How do I edit the same UILabel in every row of a TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have TableView with a custom TableViewCell loaded from an external nib file. Each cell has a  UILabel that needs to be hidden each time the **edit** button is pressed in the parent Navigation Controller.

Is there a `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDatasource` protocol method that I can use that will let me change the `alpha` level or employ the `setHidden` property on each and every visible UILabel from each instance of the TableViewCell (e.g., for all indexPath.row)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your custom cell a `UITableViewCell` subclass, or is it just custom in the sense that it has various subviews loaded from a xib file?

Comment: The latter. It's not subclassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[tableView visibleCells]` returns an array of all the cells that are visible at the moment. In your tableViewController's `setEditing` method you can use this to configure the existing cells.

You will also need to modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so that newly dequeued cells have the label set to visible / invisible as appropriate, depending on `tableView.editing`.

If your cell was a custom subclass you could override `setEditing: animated:` and make the changes there .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up employing two different methods. The first one used mutable arrays to store pointers to the specific label. The second one, which is cleaner, involved subclassing the UITableViewCell. I'm sticking to the latter method.

Thanks for your help!